# Sending confirmation mail on sign up using devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, devise

I'm using Devise for authentication and want to send a confirmation mail upon sign up, clicking on the confirmation link will activate the account, otherwise user will not be able to sign in. How to implement this feature? Please help!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Devise has inbuilt feature for this, that is Devise Confirmable module.Have a look on this:

In the below link, you will find the step-to-step process, how you can add devise confirmable in your application:

[https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-:confirmable-to-Users](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Add-%3aconfirmable-to-Users)

Hope it will help.Thanks